# Whether subset of a vector space is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I started learning Linear Algebra and was following notes, but few answers to exercise
problems can't digest. Problem is we are given with a set all vectors in $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in V_4 $ and need determine whether a given subset is a vector space or not:

1. $x_1 = 1$

In this case answer says it's a vector space but I think it's not as it will not have zero vector.

2. $x_3^2 \geq 0$

In this case answer says it's not a vector space but I think it is, as it'll have zero vector and seems to satisfy all axioms.

I've attached notes image, please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks in advance.

[Notes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66NJ3.jpg)

Comment: what is $V_4$ ?

Comment: 2. $x_3^2\ge 0$ is trivially true if the vector space is defined over the reals.  But if the vector space is over some other field that may not be the case.

Comment: @Koro $V_4$ is set of all ordered 4-tuples where each element comes from reals.

Comment: @DougM I guess it would be over reals only, don't think any such notion of $C^2$ being positive or negative exists, again happy to be corrected here

Comment: You're right on both fronts. The first is not a vector space, while the second one is, despite the apparent nonlinearity of the equation.